# Required in contact form fails

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have tried to create an simple contact form using AngularJS

code >>

```
<div class='main'>
            <h2>AngularJS Form Validation</h2>
            <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Username</td><td> <input type="text" name="s_word" ng-model="m_word" ng-pattern="word" required ng-trim="false">
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.s_word.$error.required">Required!</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.s_word.$error.pattern">Single word only!</span>
                        </td></tr>

                    <tr><td>    URL</td><td> <input type="url" name="in_url" ng-model="m_url" required>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.in_url.$error.required">Required!</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.in_url.$error.url">Not valid url!</span>
                        </td></tr>

                    <tr><td>Email </td><td><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" ng-model="m_email" ng-minlength=3 ng-maxlength=20 required />
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Required!</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.minlength">Not less that 3 char</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid Email!</span>
                        </td></tr>

                    <tr><td>
                            Phone</td><td> <input type="text" placeholder="33-333-33333" name="phone" ng-pattern="ph_numbr" ng-model="m_phone" />
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$error.required">Required!</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$error.minlength">Not less that 10 char</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$error.maxlength">Not More than 11 char</span>
                            <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.phone.$error.pattern">Pls Match Pattern [12-236-23658 ]</span>
                        </td></tr>
                    <tr><td>
                            Message</td><td><input type="text" placeholder="Message here" name="Message" ng-pattern="Msg" ng-model="m_message" ng-minlength=20 />
                             <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.Message.$error.required">Required!</span></td>
                    <tr><td>
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
            </form>
        </div>


 .main{
                margin: 10px auto;
                width:350px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                padding: 20px;  
            }
            .error{
                color:red;  
            }



  function Ctrl($scope) {
                $scope.m_word = '';
                $scope.word = /^\s*\w*\s*$/;
                $scope.m_url = 'http://example.com';
                $scope.ph_numbr = /^\+?\d{2}[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{5}$/;     
                $scope.Msg = '';    
            }
```

http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js
Angular link is granted from above link
Above I have provided full code of form. In my Chrome, phone number and message is required is not working.

Get me out of here anyone please.

Comment: could you create jsfiddle.net, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpxoVp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Angular doesn't automatically stop a form from being submitted. It's the developer's job to decide. Here's how my forms/controllers work together.

View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="form" ng-submit="create(form)" novalidate>
<!-- other form stuff -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.create = function(form) {
  if(form.$valid) {
    // form is valid, safe to submit to server
  }
};
```

Here's the reason why the last two inputs are not validating. Current code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="33-333-33333" name="phone" ng-pattern="ph_numbr" ng-model="m_phone" />
```

Here's what it should be:

```
<input required type="text" placeholder="33-333-33333" name="phone" ng-pattern="ph_numbr" ng-model="m_phone" />
```

Comment: Hello,thanks for answer my thing it doesn't "required" validate for Message and phone number

Comment: `required` doesn't validate for message and phone number because message and phone number don't have the `required` attribute set. Your first three fields do have the `required` attribute set.

Comment: Either any way to do as Required ??

Comment: hey.. i want to display success msg after its validation how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about why the form is being submitted in your case when required fields are not filled, but you can try the following work around too:

Have a function in your controller that performs the validations on required fields. Return false if they are not filled / empty. Call this function on your submit button's ng-click. Once you will return false, you will see the browser showing validation tool tips along with the required fields.

Comment: can do that for me please